# Get private variable last value out side of class OOPS

Tags: php, oop, stack, private

I have One core class and i can't modify the core class. My core class code is given below

```
class Test
{
    private $container = [];
    public function sample($input)
    {
            return array_push($this->container, $input);
    }
}
```

My extended class is given below

```
class Size extends Test
{  
  private $maxSize = 10;
  public function sizeadd($element)
  {
      //I want get the parent container 
        return parent::sample($element);
  }
}
```

I have add the values using following code

```
$sizeval = new Size(); 
$sizeval->sizeadd('1');
$sizeval->sizeadd('2');
```

Values added successfully. But my problem is I want to add 10 values only so I want the `count($this->container)` from parent class. Then I want to check the `sizeadd` function look like this

```
public function sizeadd($element)
      {
          if(count(container count)< $this->maxSize)
            return parent::sample($element);
      }
```

I unable to get the parent class `$container` `array`.

Comment: Sure you can't, it's private and is available only in `Test` class.

Comment: Isn't there a method for getting the size/count of `$container` in the class `Test`?

Comment: I want get the last $container array with values after add from my child class

Comment: @mapek: In theory there shouldn't be any way to get it. If there is then it is normally considered a bug (usually classified as a security bug). But lots of people have experienced what you are now experiencing (especially in the early days of Windows and MFC). So you will find a lot of OO languages that don't support private variables (javascript for example) or even go so far as to completely refuse to support private variables in all future versions (Perl). If your language support private variables then I'm sorry, it's not possible (or should not be possible).

Answer (score 3):

Try by changing the extended class as below:

```
class Size extends Test
{

    private $maxSize = 10;

    /**
     * To track how many elements are being added
     * 
     * @var integer
     */
    private static $count = 0;

    /**
     * Adding element in size
     * 
     * @param integer $element
     * @return integer
     */
    public function sizeadd($element)
    {
        if (self::$count < $this->maxSize) {
            self::$count = self::$count + 1;
            return parent::sample($element);
        }
    }

    /**
     * This is just for getting the current number of count
     * this is optional method.
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getCount() 
    {
        return self::$count;
    }
}
```

Comment: if i want to get the $container array means any other ways to do it.

Comment: No you can't get that as $container is private variable and it is not allowed to access out side the class. Some modifications in sizeadd method as when the value is added in parents container it will also get added in the childs temp array as 
   `  private static $tempArray = array();
    public function sizeadd($element)
    {
        if (self::$count < $this->maxSize) {
            self::$count = self::$count + 1;
             self::$tempArray[] = $element;
            return parent::sample($element);
        }
    }  `
But according to me it is not good idea.

Answer (score -1):

Create a function in base class to calculate container count, and use that function in child class to get total count of container.

```
class Test
{
    private $container = [];
    public function sample($input)
    {
            return array_push($this->container, $input);
    }
    // counts container
    public function countContainer(){
         return count($this->container);
    }
}
```

Now call this countContainer function in child class.

Comment: Test is my core class. i unable to add extra function or extra variables on that class. i have rights for access only the extended class